# Can't build RestKit for armv6

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit, armv6

I'm constantly getting warnings like that:

```
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Vendor/YAJL/NSBundle+YAJL.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6 
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Vendor/YAJL/NSObject+YAJL.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6 
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Vendor/YAJL/yajl-1.0.9/src/yajl.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6 
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Vendor/YAJL/yajl-1.0.9/src/yajl_alloc.c' of type sourcecode.c.c for architecture armv6
....
```

while trying to compile RestKit with "armv6" flag in Architectures build option. As compiler can't find rules to compile files, it doesn't compile them at all, so i can't install app on a device as it says it can't find compiled libraries. I've tried different approaches I've found in the internet, but they still don't work. Could anybody explain the core of this problem and why it occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running Xcode 4.5? Version 4.5 has dropped support for armv6

Comment: yeap, its Xcode 4.5. are there any chances to build for armv6 now?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to build for armv6 at all under Xcode 4.5. But keep in mind, that this is the iPhone 3G and earlier models. The 3GS and up (and all iPads) support armv7. So, I guess you just need to decide how important the 3G is to your bottom line.

Comment: Apparently you can fool XCode 4.5 into building for armv6: http://blog.chpwn.com/post/31824877081